# How to get the selected checkbox to display on alert

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have been really stuck on this. I tried looking everywhere and I couldn't find my answer. I am trying to make my checkbox and radio to display the box that is checked off, but it must show the selected answer when displayed on alert. Can someone please help me figure this out?

```js
  function popUp(){

    var firstName= document.getElementById("name").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var male = document.getElementById("male").checked;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked ;
    var female = document.getElementById("female").checked ;
    var location = document.getElementById("location").checked;
    var first = document.getElementById("first").checked;
    var second = document.getElementById("second").checked;
    var res = document.getElementById("res").checked;
    var a = document.getElementById("a").checked;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").checked;

    
  return alert("First name:" + firstName + "\n" + "Last name:" + lastName + "\n" + "Age:" + age + "\n" + "Gender:" + male + female +  "\n" + "Location:" + location + first + second + "\n" + "Dietary restrictions:" + res + a + b )
   
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="input.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      

<form id="new">
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input id="last"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input id="age"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="Male" >
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" >
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <br>
    <label>Location:</label>
    <input id="location" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">Miami</label>
    <input id="first" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">New York</label>
    <input id="second" type="checkbox">
    <label for="location">Houston</label>
<br>
<label>Dietary restrictions:</label>
<input id="res" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Lactose free</label>
    <input id="a" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Kosher</label>
    <input id="b" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Vegetarian</label>

<br>
    <button onclick= "popUp()" >OK</button>
</form>

<script src="input.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the value of radio button / checkbox, you can use `querySelector(. . .).value` for radio button and `querySelectorAll(. . .)` for checkbox. But you need to add `value` property in `<input />` first. For each field you also need to specify the `name`.

```js
function popUp(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstName= document.getElementById("name").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
    var location = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="location"]:checked')].map(e => e.value);
    var res = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="res"]:checked')].map(e => e.value);
    
  return alert("First name:" + firstName + "\n" + "Last name:" + lastName + "\n" + "Age:" + age + "\n" + "Gender:" + gender +  "\n" + "Location:" + location + "\n" + "Dietary restrictions:" + res )
   
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="input.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      

<form id="new">
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input id="last"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input id="age"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" >
    <label for="gender">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" >
    <label for="gender">Female</label>
    <br>
    <label>Location:</label>
    <input name="location" value="Miami" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">Miami</label>
    <input name="location" value="New York" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">New York</label>
    <input name="location" value="Houston" type="checkbox">
    <label for="location">Houston</label>
<br>
<label>Dietary restrictions:</label>
<input name="res" type="checkbox" value="Lactose free">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Lactose free</label>
    <input name="res" value="Kosher" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Kosher</label>
    <input name="res" value="Vegetarian" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Vegetarian</label>

<br>
    <button onclick= "popUp(event)" >OK</button>
</form>

<script src="input.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the value from the form to the function.

So instead off look for the click on the button, you should wait for the submit off the form.

Then on the onsubmit, you send the value of the form to the function, and here you can easily extract the values you need from the form.

Now you have all the data you need on the event parameter.
event.target gets you the form that have been submitted to the function.
event.target.name will give you the name input.

Just remember to use event.preventDefault(). otherwise the browser will send the information and reload the page because it is trying to submit the data.

```js
  function popUp(event){
    event.preventDefault();
var targetForm = event.target
var firstName= targetForm.name.value;
var lastName = targetForm.last.value;
var age = targetForm.age.value;
var male = targetForm.male.checked;
var female = targetForm.female.checked ;
var location = targetForm.location.checked;
var first = targetForm.first.checked;
var second = targetForm.second.checked;
var res = targetForm.res.checked;
var a = targetForm.a.checked;
var b = targetForm.b.checked;
    
  return alert("First name:" + firstName + "\n" + "Last name:" + lastName + "\n" + "Age:" + age + "\n" + "Gender:" + male + female +  "\n" + "Location:" + location + first + second + "\n" + "Dietary restrictions:" + res + a + b )
   
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="input.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      

<form id="new" onsubmit="popUp(event)">
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input id="last"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Age:</label>
    <input id="age"  type="text">
    <br>
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="Male" >
    <label for="male">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" >
    <label for="female">Female</label>
    <br>
    <label>Location:</label>
    <input id="location" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">Miami</label>
    <input id="first" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="location">New York</label>
    <input id="second" type="checkbox">
    <label for="location">Houston</label>
<br>
<label>Dietary restrictions:</label>
<input id="res" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Lactose free</label>
    <input id="a" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Kosher</label>
    <input id="b" type="checkbox">
    <label for="Dietary restrictions">Vegetarian</label>

<br>
</form>
    <button type="submit" form="new" value="Submit">OK</button>

<script src="input.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```